# Insert additional products inside a grid when clicked on any products

Tags: angular

Functional requirement:

- The products are displayed in a grid format.
- On click of any product it'll call 6 more products from the API.
- The new set of products should be inserted rite next to the product which has been clicked.
- The other products in the grid has to be shifted to later position on the grid (rite next to newly added products).

Comment: unclear what you are asking and what problem you are actually facing. Are you facing animation issues?

Comment: its a bit difficult to understand your question hence answering it. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask &  look into it once

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass id on click then changes its property using render2 angular library or you can do it using simple js too passing id on click is like

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class=" col-md-4" *ngFor="let x of list; let i = index " style="padding:15px;" >
   <div class="card " id="x._id +'i'" "(click)="clickme(x._id,i)">
     <div class="card-body ">
       <img src="{{x.productImage}}" class="rounded"  >
       <div>{{x.product_name}}</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```